# Error After Installing Website in magento 2 js

Tags: magento2.3, requirejs, nginx, permissions, requirejs-config.js

I just installed magento 2 and I come across a bug that won't let me get lost on my admin page

[image: admin]

[image: index]

i use :
Nginx Php7.2 Varnish 4 and Percona Server on Debian 9

I believe the problem is in the version1577742505 / ... folder.

because it does not exist in my sftp

Comment: version1577**** folder will not exist. change the ownership and permission of <magento-root>/pub folder recursively as per Magento dev docs. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Comment: Have you run the static:content:deploy command?